# Alguien me puede explicar como se recibe un ArrayList al llamar a un método en Java?

Tags: java, arraylist

Intento enviar un ArrayList como parámetro a un método en Java, y lo consigo sin problemas

Lo que no consigo es como declarar el ArrayList que se recibe al llamar a un método que te retorna un nuevo ArrayList, pues me subrraya en rojo la palabra de ArrayList

```
//metodo que llama al métodoCrearArrayList enviando un ArrayList por parámetro y recibe a su vez un nuevo ArrayList 
//(Aquí es donde tengo el error, que me subraya en rojo el texto ArrayList
ArrayList<Integer> viejoArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
ArrayList<Integer> nuevoArrayList = metodoCrearArrayList(viejoArrayList);

//metodo que recibe ArrayList por parámetro y retorna un nuevo ArrayList
public static ArrayList<Integer> metodoCrearArrayList(ArrayList<Integer> miArrayList){       
     ArrayList<Integer> nuevoArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     return nuevoArrayList
}
```

También me da error si trato de enviar el ArrayList junto a dos int, sin embargo si quito los int, deja de dar error

```
//llamada al método
metodoImprimirResultados(resultado, ando, dor);

//método al que llamo que me subrraya en rojo
public static void metodoImprimirResultados(ArrayList<Integer> resultado, ando, dor){
    System.out.println("El resultado de multiplicar " + ando + " * " + dor + " es de: ");
    for (int k = 0; k < resultado.size(); k++){
        System.out.print(resultado.get(k));
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Hombre, aparte de marcártelo en rojo te aparecerá algún mensaje informativo, no? Lo más probable es que te esté indicando que no encuentra la clase ArrayList porque no has realizado un import, más concretamente `import java.util.ArrayList;` Lo de los int, el error en el código que has puesto es que no has declarado su tipo en la signatura. Poniendo esto `public static void metodoImprimirResultados(ArrayList<Integer> resultado, int ando, int dor){`, tú codigo compila.

Comment: Pues exactamente ese era mi error. Seré inútil. Pues llevaba con ello tres días. Muchísimas gracias. Si me haces el favor, podrías convertir tu cometnario en respuesta, y así te lo agradezco votando a favor y aceptando tu respuesta. Muchas gracias

Comment: De nada, hombre, para eso estamos. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo más probable es que te esté indicando que no encuentra la clase `ArrayList` porque no has realizado un import, más concretamente

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

Lo de los int, el error en el código que has puesto es que no has declarado su tipo en la signatura. Poniendo esto tu código compila

```
public static void metodoImprimirResultados(ArrayList<Integer> resultado, int ando, int dor) {
```

La mayoría de IDEs tienen ayudas para gestionar las importaciones y normalmente te ofrecen la solución al problema cuando pasas el ratón por encima de la clase subrayada en rojo. Yo uso principalmente Eclipse y aparte de lo que te indico si pones el cursor enmedio de la clase o justo al final y pulsas Ctrl+Espacio te incluye la línea de import. Siempre que la clase se encuentre dentro de las dependencias declaradas del proyecto.

Respecto a esto último, cuando empieces a usar clases de librerías de terceros tendrás que acordarte de incluir las dependencias correspondientes en el fichero de configuración de Maven o de Gradle.